# How does Hunger of Hadar behave in confined space?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, cover

Hunger of Hadar has a curious wording:

> A 20-foot-radius **sphere** of blackness and bitter cold **appears**, centered on a point with range and lasting for the duration.

Compare this to Fireball:

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range then **blossoms** with a low roar **into an explosion** of flame. [...] The fire spreads around corners.

And Darkness:

> Magical darkness **spreads** from a point you choose within range **to fill a 15-foot radius sphere** for the duration. The darkness spreads around corners.

Total cover rule [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Cover) states:

> A target with total cover can't be targeted directly by an attack or a spell, although **some spells can reach such a target by including it in an area of effect**.

---

**What would allow or require Hunger of Hadar to appear in a different shape or size?**

Most simply this would be mundane walls, though I guess manufacturing a glass container of desired shape wouldn't be hard, and then there're spells like Force Cage and Leomund's Tiny Hut. These would block most spells, but the HoH spell description is very explicit... *a 20-foot radius sphere appears*, no buts, no ifs. Is there a rule which would override the HoH description?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The *hunger of Hadar* spell follows [the normal spellcasting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect)

> [...] **Every area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the spell's energy erupts.** [...]
>
> [...] A spell's effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin. If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a location within the area of effect, that location isn't included in the spell's area. To block one of these imaginary lines, an obstruction must provide total cover. [...]

> [...] You select a sphere's point of origin, and the sphere extends outward from that point. The sphere's size is expressed as a radius in feet that extends from the point. [...]

Unless a spell *explicitly* counters these rules, it will follow them. An example of such an explicitly stated exception is the [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) spell:

> [...] The fire spreads around corners. [...]

The *hunger of Hadar* spell does *not* have a similar explicit exception to the rules on spellcasting and areas of effect and so it does *not* have any sort of unusual behavior. Thus, the spell's area of effect is blocked by walls and obstacles just like almost every other area of effect in the game.

---

Furthermore, I do not believe the use of the verb "appears" is meaningful evidence of any sort. The *burning hands* spell similarly makes a sheet of fire "appear" and *fireball* causes an explosion to "appear" while *darkness* causes a dark void to "appear". These could *all* be described using that same verb and it does not lead to the conclusion that they should *all* go around corners or come into existence immediately. The verb used is nothing special.

Comment: There are a few spells with comparable language, such as Insect Plague and Storm Sphere, those are probably a strong argument for total cover blocking HoH. Burning hands uses a diffetent language which IMO highlights the difference anfnis an opposite argument if anything.